# Arrow keys type capital letters instead of moving the cursor

Tags: macos, terminal, vim

I've installed the latest vim using homebrew and also installed mac-vim from the google code homepage.
in mac-vim everything works fine. but when I run vim in terminal.app in mac and go to insert mode I'll get A B C D for arrow keys which is extremely annoying.

I googled it and tried all the solutions but nothing is working for me!

it gets intresting when I run vim with `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N` then the arrow keys start to function normally in insert mode.

my vimrc files are a clone of [janus (from carlhuda)](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus)

do you have the same problem in terminal? is there a way to fix it in terminal.app?

Comment: What does `:verb imap <down>` tell you? (`<down`, `<up>`, `<left`> and `<right>`).

Comment: `set nocompatible` doesn't help?

Comment: @Benoit i  <Down>      *@<C-R>=<SNR>22_FlushBuffer()<CR><Down>
        Last set from ~/Dropbox/dotfiles/vim/plugin/autoclose.vim

Comment: @khachik I'm already setting nocomatible at the top of my vimrc file

Comment: @Benoit great hint man, thanks. it was caused by the autoclose.vim. I removed the plugin and everything start working normally. now I wonder how can I solved this problem and keep the plugin. cause it's a really handy one in mac-vim. I prefer to have it in terminal

Comment: @Allen, same problem here. Have you found solution yet?

Comment: I just removed the autoclose.vim from the plugins folder and it solved my problem.

Comment: same here, removed autoclose.vim and keys were working again.

Answer (score 47):

Just create an empty ".vimrc file in the home directory of the remote machine. It started working fine for me.

```
touch ~/.vimrc
```

Comment: Worked great for me on Mavericks 10.9.2 with iTerm2! Thanks :)

Comment: Worked for me too on 10.9.3 with zsh

Comment: Confirmed on 10.9.4. Great answer!

Comment: Works! Error started with yosemite

Comment: Work like a charm, thanks. It saves my day. Don't know how it's still a problem until now.

Comment: This solved the problem with the arrow keys but the delete/backspace key didn't work on OSx El Captain with iTerm2. I've posted an answer with the solution that worked for me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @rodorgas This works because vim turns on 'nocompatible' mode automatically when `~/.vimrc` exists. Here is a bit more about it http://superuser.com/a/543327

Answer (score 22):

You need to set no compatible mode in the vim
Try following command in normal mode

`:set nocompatible`

Comment: This means "use Vim settings rather than Vi settings," correct?

Comment: Yes, use vim behavior instead of vi behavior

Comment: You can achieve same by doing `touch ~/.vimrc`

Answer (score 13):

This works for me:

```
map ^[[A <up>
map ^[[B <down>
map ^[[C <right>
map ^[[D <left>
```

To type the sequence for each arrow key, you need to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, then the arrow key.

For example, to type the first line:
<kbd>m</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>space</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>space</kbd>, <kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>></kbd>

This also might work:

```
set t_ku=^[[A
set t_kd=^[[B
set t_kr=^[[C
set t_kl=^[[D
```

[More information is available here.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell)

Comment: Hooray! Thanks @todofixthis ! I tried a whole bunch of different fixes for this; it was using ctrl-v to set the map that did it.

Answer (score 11):

I'm on a MacBook Pro with OSx El Captain (version 10.11.1) and was having the same problem after updating my Vim with Homebrew.

My Vim version is 7.4.1063.

I was having the problem with the Terminal app as well as the iTerm app (build 2.1.4).

To solve this problem, I followed some of the instructions in the previous answers from @devsathish and @Kailash. The steps I followed were:

1 - Create a .vimrc file with `touch ~/.vimrc`
2 - Add the following to it:

```
set nocompatible
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Now the arrow keys and the delete/backspace keys work as expected. I didn't have to change my `$TERM` env variable as suggested in some of the previous answers.

I hope this helps others with the same problem.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine while other things said before did not work. Thank you very much, you saved my Vim! ^_^

Comment: Glad to help @DavidG.

Comment: Thanks! And I found a post to explain how `set backspace=indent,eol,start` works. http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2162/why-doesnt-the-backspace-key-work-in-insert-mode

Answer (score 7):

I'm using iTerm2 with [spf13-vim](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim), and have same problem today.

It caused by removing plugin vim-autoclose. [This solution fixed it.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell#Solution_21)

Just add following lines into your .vimrc

```
if &term[:4] == "xterm" || &term[:5] == 'screen' || &term[:3] == 'rxvt'
  inoremap <silent> <C-[>OC <RIGHT>
endif
```

Comment: cool, it works.  at first i was blaming some plugins, but after testing vim w/o .vimrc on iTerm and Terminal.app, i'm not so sure wasn't it like that all the time.

Answer (score 6):

This is usually caused by the wrong $TERM environment variable. Not sure which ones are supported on your system but you can try with "linux" or "vt320":

export TERM=linux

Answer (score 4):

To make sure that my Terminal is working great with Vim 7.3 in Show Leopard, I have done the following:

1. Installed the latest Vim via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).
2. Set path to enable the latest Vim. E.g.: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`
3. Added `export TERM=linux` to my `.bashrc` file.
4. Created a `.vimrc` file with some options (formerly linked here, link went dead.)

When so is done, everything should work. However, I have experienced that some text don't seem to remove, like its protected until I either `dd` or `x`. Has anyone experienced something similar? Also, please share comments on my small guide above.

Comment: Im on yosemite and just adding export TERM=linux worked for me

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me. Running vim in blank state with `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N` made it work ok, and because I had not installed any plugins, I knew problem is in my vimrc. So I started commenting out sections from it, and at one moment problem disappeared.

The culprit was this line:
inoremap

Even though it was recommended in a very well written course (http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/10.html), it broke the arrow keys on Mac OS X 10.10. Basically, you shouldn't overwrite esc, as the other SO answer explains: [How to disable Esc and cursor keys in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488232/how-to-disable-esc-and-cursor-keys-in-vim)

Answer (score 3):

I have used following code in my .vimrc file, and it has resolved my problem with arrow keys.

```
...
...
" Use Vim settings, rather than Vi settings (much better!).
" This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.
set nocompatible

" allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start
...
...

" CTRL-U in insert mode deletes a lot.  Use CTRL-G u to first break undo,
" so that you can undo CTRL-U after inserting a line break.
inoremap <C-U> <C-G>u<C-U>

" In many terminal emulators the mouse works just fine, thus enable it.
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=a
endif
...
...
```

I have posted my complete `.vimrc` file [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419639/vim-shows-garbage-characters-on-pressing-arrow-key-after-opening-a-file/10194428#10194428). Hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me (based on initial solution from @Phoenix above)

```
imap ^[OA <ESC>kli
imap ^[OB <ESC>jli
imap ^[OC <ESC>lli
imap ^[OD <ESC>hli
```

for each 
^[
type the sequence  press ctrl-v, then ESC

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with another plugin. I solved it by hardcoding these alternative mappings in the script itself, the first line of each pair was problematic, the second line is the fix:

```
VIM::command "#{map} <Right> :call <SID>#{prefix}KeyPressed(9)<CR>"
VIM::command "#{map} ^[OC    :call <SID>#{prefix}KeyPressed(9)<CR>"

VIM::command "#{map} <Left>  :call <SID>#{prefix}KeyPressed(23)<CR>"
VIM::command "#{map} ^[OD    :call <SID>#{prefix}KeyPressed(23)<CR>"

VIM::command "#{map} <Down>  :call <SID>#{prefix}KeyPressed(14)<CR>"
VIM::command "#{map} ^[OB    :call <SID>#{prefix}KeyPressed(14)<CR>"

VIM::command "#{map} <Up>    :call <SID>#{prefix}KeyPressed(16)<CR>"
VIM::command "#{map} ^[OA    :call <SID>#{prefix}KeyPressed(16)<CR>"
```

`^[` is obtained by hitting `<C-v><Esc>`.

Maybe you can try something like:

```
map <Right> ^[OC
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually resolved this on OS X Mavericks (10.9) by removing `set noesckeys` from `~/.vimrc`

Comment: This fixed my issue perfectly with iTerm2. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem as well. It has multiple causes, but one of them is vim using vi rather than vim behavior by default. Surprisingly, this can be triggered by the location of your vimrc file.

For example, if you delete your .vimrc from your home directory and move the contents to the system-wide vimrc file, vim will start using vi defaults. With the Mac Terminal, this will give you ABCD from arrows in insert mode. Add "set nocompatible" to the system-wide vimrc, which will force vim to use vim defaults, and the arrows will work again.