# VIM ubuntu system wide plugin directory

Tags: vim

where is the vim plugin directory in ubuntu. I need to remove the autoclose.vim plugin to fix problem described here:
[Arrow keys type capital letters instead of moving the cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303830/vim-problem-with-arrow-keys-in-insert-mode-in-mac-terminal-app)

Comment: check `~/.vim/bundle/autoclose` or `~/.vim/plugin/autoclose.vim`

Comment: This is for the root user, I do not see a .vim folder in my directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [`:h runtimepath`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27rtp%27) for a complete description of possible locations for
your folder (considering you're not using a bundle plugin). Here is an excerpt:

```
                                *'runtimepath'* *'rtp'* *vimfiles*
'runtimepath' 'rtp'     string  (default:
                                        Unix, Mac OS X: "$HOME/.vim,
                                                $VIM/vimfiles,
                                                $VIMRUNTIME,
                                                $VIM/vimfiles/after,
                                                $HOME/.vim/after"
                                        ...
                        global
                        {not in Vi}
        This is a list of directories which will be searched for runtime
        files:
          filetype.vim  filetypes by file name |new-filetype|
          scripts.vim   filetypes by file contents |new-filetype-scripts|
          autoload/     automatically loaded scripts |autoload-functions|
          colors/       color scheme files |:colorscheme|
          compiler/     compiler files |:compiler|
          doc/          documentation |write-local-help|
          ftplugin/     filetype plugins |write-filetype-plugin|
          indent/       indent scripts |indent-expression|
          keymap/       key mapping files |mbyte-keymap|
          lang/         menu translations |:menutrans|
          menu.vim      GUI menus |menu.vim|
          plugin/       plugin scripts |write-plugin|
          print/        files for printing |postscript-print-encoding|
          spell/        spell checking files |spell|
          syntax/       syntax files |mysyntaxfile|
          tutor/        files for vimtutor |tutor|

        And any other file searched for with the |:runtime| command.

        The defaults for most systems are setup to search five locations:
        1. In your home directory, for your personal preferences.
        2. In a system-wide Vim directory, for preferences from the system
           administrator.
        3. In $VIMRUNTIME, for files distributed with Vim.
                                                        *after-directory*
        4. In the "after" directory in the system-wide Vim directory.  This is
           for the system administrator to overrule or add to the distributed
           defaults (rarely needed)
        5. In the "after" directory in your home directory.  This is for
           personal preferences to overrule or add to the distributed defaults
           or system-wide settings (rarely needed).

        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading the rules on `'runtimepath'`, I think it is easier to get a list of all the installed scripts:

```
:scriptnames
```

This will show the complete path to each script that vim has loaded.  If there are only a few, then you can spot the one you are looking for (`autoclose.vim` for the OP).

If the list is long, then you can capture the output of `scriptnames` in the `a` register (or any other), paste it into an empty buffer, and search for the name of your plugin:

```
:redir @a
:scriptnames
:redir END
:new
:put a
:/autoclose\.vim
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow Eric'comment.

That said, I have these lines in my .vimrc:

**--EDIT--**

I know this answer is not the chosen one but I learned something thanks to ZyX comments so here is an edit.

The lines below should be written as follow:

```
nnoremap <Esc>A <up>
nnoremap <Esc>B <down>
nnoremap <Esc>C <right>
nnoremap <Esc>D <left>
inoremap <Esc>A <up>
inoremap <Esc>B <down>
inoremap <Esc>C <right>
inoremap <Esc>D <left>
```

I'm afraid a **lot** of people do the exact same mistake I did: the raw escape code solution is like everywhere on the net from the Vim wiki to SO via lots of forums.

**--END EDIT--**

```
nnoremap <type ctrl+v then Esc to obtain a single char that looks like ^[>A <up>
nnoremap <type ctrl+v then Esc to obtain a single char that looks like ^[>B <down>
nnoremap <type ctrl+v then Esc to obtain a single char that looks like ^[>C <right>
nnoremap <type ctrl+v then Esc to obtain a single char that looks like ^[>D <left>
inoremap <type ctrl+v then Esc to obtain a single char that looks like ^[>A <up>
inoremap <type ctrl+v then Esc to obtain a single char that looks like ^[>B <down>
inoremap <type ctrl+v then Esc to obtain a single char that looks like ^[>C <right>
inoremap <type ctrl+v then Esc to obtain a single char that looks like ^[>D <left>
```

and didn't need to remove any plugin.

Comment: Don't add raw command codes into the file, you already have `<...>` notation and «character that looks like ^[» is expressed as `<Esc>`. Surprising, isn't it? Note that whenever I saw such problems `<Arrow>` outputted `<Esc>O[A-D]`, not `<Esc>[A-D]`.

Comment: That's what you get when you follow blindly random forum posts. Of course I knew that `^[` meant `<Esc>` but I believed the two notations had different "weight" (by lack of a better word) the use of one over the other being dictated by the particular context. Thank you for the info, I'm going to try it right now. Do you have a specific reason for keeping raw command codes out of .vimrc? Beside the perfectly fine reason that we already have `<...>` I mean.

Comment: Besides a bit of h/l moves inconvenience the more raw control codes you have the more is the chance that mercurial which keeps my configuration will take this file as binary (and thus won't show diffs). In addition, if you format your plugin with `:TOhtml`, `:Format` or such you will either get these characters not displayed or displayed as `^[` (and same will be copied). Don't you see by yourself: instead of writing `<Esc>` you wrote `<type ctrl+v then Esc to obtain a single char that looks like ^[>`?

Comment: And I can't remember how is bitbucket/github/{VCS hosting that you are using} will display these characters... but I bet you whatever they choose it won't get copied as a control code (I may be wrong though).

Comment: I can say about bitbucket: it displays raw escape as a rectangle (as for any unknown character) and it gets copied as an escape (so I was wrong in previous comment), but there is another inconvenience: you can't use `<C-r>+` to paste escape, you need `<C-r><C-r>+`. It also does not get pasted from Opera (guess it is related to non-ASCII character pasting problem that was introduced when Opera switched to a self-written toolkit and vim updated to 7.3 with some more X clipboard handling strictness).

Comment: So, these characters are inconvenient to share, inconvenient to paste and inconvenient to navigate. They are more convenient to type (at least escape and pastetoggle key cannot be inserted in this notation using `<C-k><Key>`), but you may always do `inoremap <C-v><Esc> <LT>Esc>` if you wish. You still insist on using them?

Comment: Haha no I won't insist. I was just passing on "knowledge" that I didn't understand and that I actually found painfully awkward. Thanks for everything. And I'm going to edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: The raw escape code solution should be used if you care about vi (within vim with 'compatible' set you could just use `inoremap <special> <Esc>OA <Up>`); I guess, this is why it is so popular. But as far as I know, if you are using vi, you can't use `<Arrow>` in rhs. And I can't say what should you use instead.