# Add GoLang syntax highlighting for VIM

Tags: vim, go, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to add Go language syntax highlighting to VIM on ubuntu with resources and direction supplied here http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/vim/.

Go comes with a `go.vim` file that contains syntax settings for VIM and the above page offers the following instructions

**Place $GOROOT/misc/vim/syntax/go.vim in ~/.vim/syntax/ and put the following in ~/.vim/ftdetect/go.vim:**

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.go set filetype=go
```

This is more or less the same vein of procedure for customizing vim syntax I've seen elsewhere
([Vim 7.3 on Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't have 'ftplugin' directory anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962233/vim-7-3-on-ubuntu-12-10-doesnt-have-ftplugin-directory-anywhere) and https://github.com/jnwhiteh/vim-golang/blob/master/readme.txt)

So I think I'm doing the right thing when I create directories:
~/.vim
~/.vim/syntax
~/.vim/ftdetect

and follow the above instructions by adding

go.vim to ~/.vim/syntax/
and creating a file, go.vim, in ~/.vim/ftdetect/ which contains

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.go set filetype=go
```

Yet syntax highlighting does not seem to occur. Is there something I need to do to force VIM to look at these new settings files?

Comment: For whoever gets here from Google, nowadays there is this nice package for Vim: https://github.com/fatih/vim-go that wraps several goodies for Go.

Comment: Just wanted to document here that the official go documentation at

https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/IDEsAndTextEditorPlugins

points to https://github.com/fatih/vim-go as well. It includes go.vim, if you didn't get it in your installation for whatever reason (e.g. you got it from a package repo that didn't include it) and is easy to install with Vundle.

Comment: thx @maths the code.googe  now also points to https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/IDEsAndTextEditorPlugins

Comment: Also to Google arrivals, the page in the question is no longer updated, and (on my distribution at least) there is no `go.vim` file under `{go}/misc/vim`

Comment: The /misc/vim solution no longer works. Use Vim-go instead. Beginners may want to follow https://medium.com/@hackintoshrao/setting-up-vim-for-golang-programming-beginner-cheat-sheat-44181be99b9b. Make sure that you are using using Vim 7.4.1689 or newer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can just add these lines to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set rtp+=$GOROOT/misc/vim
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

**EDIT** This assumes `filetype plugin indent off` before these lines (i.e. beginning of `.vimrc` file) and may cause problems if it's not. See @peterSO's answer below for the safer version.

Comment: I am not sure if anyone else has had this problem but, I tried inserting those lines in my .vimrc and it didn't work. I tried echoing $GOROOT and a empty line came out. What is the path for $GOROOT suppose to be? It should be some directory but I am not sure why mine failed to have any content, did you encounter this problem?

Comment: @charlie-parker: how did you install go? I recently installed it on an Ubuntu 12.04 via `apt-get install golang`. It appears that /misc/vim is not included in the subsequently installed packages.

A solution is to use the [vim-golang](https://github.com/jnwhiteh/vim-golang) repository (preferably in conjunction with something like [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen)).

Comment: @CharlieParker I use a manual installation and have `$GOROOT` set manually in `~/.profile`. Since it's a manual installation I set it to `/usr/local/go`. Alternatively you can use @trobter 's solution which should work as well.

Comment: I did the automatic install. However, I think I understand that its ok for Unix not to know about $GOROOT. I figured that it was set correctly since go env showed how it was set. I didn't know that. Thanks though!

Comment: As of 2015 January (maybe earlier), the `vim` directory has been removed from `$GOROOT/misc/`.

Comment: Got: `E79: Cannot expand wildcards` error message probably because `$GOROOT/misc/vim` doesn't longer exists. This answer solved for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21164736/20654

Comment: `syntax on` is the key

Comment: The first 5 or so answers are way too old. Save yourself a headache and look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52640897/6740589.

Answer (score 65):

UPDATE:

> [Go 1.4 Release Notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4)
>
> [Miscellany](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#misc)
>
> The standard repository's top-level misc directory used to contain Go
>   support for editors and IDEs: plugins, initialization
>   scripts and so on. Maintaining these was becoming time-consuming and
>   needed external help because many of the editors listed were not used
>   by members of the core team. It also required us to make decisions
>   about which plugin was best for a given editor, even for editors we do
>   not use.
>        The Go community at large is much better suited to managing this information. In Go 1.4, therefore, this support has been removed from
>   the repository. Instead, there is a curated, informative list of
>   what's available on a [wiki page](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/IDEsAndTextEditorPlugins).

---

The standard Go distribution includes Go files for Vim in `go/misc/vim/`. This directory contains a `readme.txt` file which contains installation instructions.

> [`readme.txt`](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/misc/vim/readme.txt)
>
> Vim plugins for Go (`http://golang.org`)
>
> To use all the Vim plugins, add these lines to your `$HOME/.vimrc`.
>
> ```
> " Some Linux distributions set filetype in /etc/vimrc.
> " Clear filetype flags before changing runtimepath to force Vim to reload them.
> filetype off
> filetype plugin indent off
> set runtimepath+=$GOROOT/misc/vim
> filetype plugin indent on
> syntax on
> ```
>
> If you want to select fewer plugins, use the instructions in the rest
>   of this file.
>
> <<..SNIP..>>

Comment: Also check out vim-golang, which is a mirror of the official Vim plugins for golang that can easily be installed/updated via Vundle, etc. https://github.com/jnwhiteh/vim-golang

Comment: I am not sure if anyone else has had this problem but, I tried inserting those lines in my .vimrc and it didn't work. I tried echoing $GOROOT and a empty line came out. What is the path for $GOROOT suppose to be? It should be some directory but I am not sure why mine failed to have any content, did you encounter this problem?

Comment: @CharlieParker I found that $GOROOT does not get defined after installing go on ubuntu (via apt-get) so I manually added this to my .bashrc file (`export GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"`) - in addition I had to download the tar.gz from https://code.google.com/p/go/wiki/Downloads?tm=2 and extract the `misc` folder into place (`/usr/lib/go/misc/`) as this is not done when installing via ubuntu. ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/zQhCYp0BZp8

Comment: See answers below, /misc/vim has been deprecated and you should use vim-go  (or other options) instead.

Answer (score 40):

On Debian, I suppose it's the same on ubuntu, you just :

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gocomplete gocode vim-syntax-go
vim-addon-manager install go-syntax
vim-addon-manager install gocode
```

Comment: My Wheezy install has no _vim-gocomplete_ or _gocode_ packages.

Comment: You're right : http://packages.debian.org/vim-gocomplete only for jessie and sid. But golang is only available in jessie and sid ... with .deb package.

Comment: Works in ubuntu 15 as well

Answer (score 21):

For the best syntax highlighting try https://github.com/fatih/vim-go

It's a new project that consolidates many vim plugins and adds a lot of features. From the readme:

- Improved Syntax highlighting, such as Functions, Operators, Methods..
- Auto completion support via gocode
- Better gofmt on save, keeps cursor position and doesn't break your undo history
- Go to symbol/declaration with godef
- Automatically import packages via goimports
- Compile and go build your package, install it with go install
- go run quickly your current file/files
- Run go test and see any errors in quickfix window
- Lint your code with golint
- Run your code trough go vet to catch static errors.
- Advanced source analysis tool with oracle
- List all source files and dependencies
- Checking with errcheck for unchecked errors.
- Integrated and improved snippets. Supports ultisnips or neosnippet
- Share your current code to play.golang.org

Comment: In CentOS, I succeed to install vim-go with yum. `#yum install  vim-go`

Comment: [This project is sunset](https://arslan.io/2018/10/09/taking-an-indefinite-sabbatical-from-my-projects/)

Comment: @ColeBittel, did you read the blog post you linked?  vim-go is actively maintained, as announced in the very blog post you linked to.  The project *founder* no longer works on it, that's all.

Answer (score 9):

on 25/Jan/2015

Please see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/IDEsAndTextEditorPlugins as now all editor & shell support in Go repo is removed (https://codereview.appspot.com/105470043)

Answer (score 5):

I did not find instructions on turning on vim syntax highlighting for CentOS 7. Have tested the ensuing instructions to work on CentOS 7.3.1611. First, create the following directory in your home directory:

```
$ mkdir ~/.vim/ftdetect/
```

Then, create a file named, `go.vim` inside the above directory with the contents:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.go set filetype=go
```

Download the syntax definition file for Go: [vim.go](https://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11735). Transfer it to the right system-wide directory so that multiple users can share:

```
$ sudo mv -i go.vim /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Upvote this, people! This is the most recent answer and it works like a charm on CentOS 7.5.1804.

Comment: I would just like to clarify the above
"Download the syntax definition file for Go: vim.go into `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/go.vim`". 
The above solution does work on CentOS 6 and 7

Comment: Fantastic, most other resources all end up not working for anything remotely old, this does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

For whatever reason outside of my own decision making, we got Golang installed on our dev VMs by Debian packages. This particular distribution of vim doesn't come with any of the goodies for vim as far as I was able to tell from a search around for it. Anyways, I decided to go the vundle route in order to rapidly deploy the goodies to all these dev VMs. You could probably work this method into puppet or something if you'd like, we didn't do that though. Anyways, here's what I did:

Step 1: Install vundle:
https://github.com/gmarik/vundle

Step 2: put this line in your .vimrc (It's from here, of course: https://github.com/jnwhiteh/vim-golang ), and then run vim from the command line like `vim +BundleInstall +qall` or from within vim with `:BundleInstall`

```
Bundle 'jnwhiteh/vim-golang'
```

Step 3: Save this little bash script I whipped up as govim.sh or whatever, `chmod +x govim.sh`, and run it like `./govim.sh`

Script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir $HOME/.vim/ftdetect
mkdir $HOME/.vim/syntax
mkdir $HOME/.vim/autoload
mkdir $HOME/.vim/autoload/go
mkdir $HOME/.vim/ftplugin
mkdir $HOME/.vim/ftplugin/go
mkdir $HOME/.vim/indent
mkdir $HOME/.vim/compiler
mkdir $HOME/.vim/plugin
mkdir $HOME/.vim/plugin/godoc
ln -s $HOME/.vim/bundle/vim-golang/ftdetect/gofiletype.vim $HOME/.vim/ftdetect
ln -s $HOME/.vim/bundle/vim-golang/syntax/go.vim $HOME/.vim/syntax/
ln -s $HOME/.vim/bundle/vim-golang/autoload/go/complete.vim $HOME/.vim/autoload/go/
ln -s $HOME/.vim/bundle/vim-golang/ftplugin/go.vim $HOME/.vim/ftplugin/
ln -s $HOME/.vim/bundle/vim-golang/ftplugin/go/*.vim $HOME/.vim/ftplugin/go/
ln -s $HOME/.vim/bundle/vim-golang/indent/go.vim $HOME/.vim/indent/
ln -s $HOME/.vim/bundle/vim-golang/compiler/go.vim $HOME/.vim/compiler/
ln -s $HOME/.vim/bundle/vim-golang/plugin/godoc/godoc.vim $HOME/.vim/plugin/godoc/
ln -s $HOME/.vim/bundle/vim-golang/syntax/godoc.vim $HOME/.vim/syntax/
```

Kaching! You now have all the goodies installed, and someone correct me if I'm wrong on this but perhaps more than what comes with the official Golang distribution. I don't know about this either having not tried it yet, but I think that the runtimepath/rtp gets clobbered if you use Vundle with the other answers here anyways.

Answer (score 4):

It should be easy as 1, 2, 3 :

1. Download the file [vim.go](https://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11735) and place in in `~/.vim/syntax` under the name `go.vim` (create the directory `syntax` if you don't already have it).
2. If you don't already have the file `~/.vim/ftdetect/go.vim`, create it (and the folder if necessary).
3. In `.vim/ftdetect/go.vim`, add the following line : `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.go set filetype=go`

Comment: "place in in ~/.vim/syntax under the name vim.go" should instead be "under the name **go.vim**". Then it works :)

Comment: This is the best Answer

Answer (score 3):

This [page](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/vim/) says that:

```
Place $GOROOT/misc/vim/syntax/go.vim in ~/.vim/syntax/ 
and put the following in ~/.vim/ftdetect/go.vim:

au BufRead,BufNewFile *.go set filetype=go
```

It worked for me, only i did not find the /misc/vim/go.vim directory at first. So i copied the files from another computer that had installed go on /usr/local/go/...

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in MAC

- Install vim-go - https://github.com/fatih/vim-go
- Set the .vimrc to the following

```html
let g:tagbar_type_go = {
        \ 'ctagstype' : 'go',
        \ 'kinds'     : [
                \ 'p:package',
                \ 'i:imports:1',
                \ 'c:constants',
                \ 'v:variables',
                \ 't:types',
                \ 'n:interfaces',
                \ 'w:fields',
                \ 'e:embedded',
                \ 'm:methods',
                \ 'r:constructor',
                \ 'f:functions'
        \ ],
        \ 'sro' : '.',
        \ 'kind2scope' : {
                \ 't' : 'ctype',
                \ 'n' : 'ntype'
        \ },
        \ 'scope2kind' : {
                \ 'ctype' : 't',
                \ 'ntype' : 'n'
        \ },
        \ 'ctagsbin'  : 'gotags',
        \ 'ctagsargs' : '-sort -silent'
\ }

let g:go_highlight_structs = 1
let g:go_highlight_methods = 1
let g:go_highlight_functions = 1
let g:go_highlight_operators = 1
let g:go_highlight_build_constraints = 1
syntax on
```

- Install gotags - e.g. brew install gotags
- Generate ctags - e.g. gorags -R . > ./tags
- Open vim from the new shell

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the directions above were slightly ambiguous.

`~/.vim/syntax/go.vim` should have the same contents as `~/.vim/ftdetect/go.vim`

only `~/.vim/ftdetect/go.vim` must be appended with `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.go set filetype=go`.

If taken literally, the directions tell you to create a file `~/.vim/ftdetect/go.vim` containing only

```
         au BufRead,BufNewFile *.go set filetype=go
```

I suppose that's where contextual knowledge should kick in. Only I'd never done this before and had no such context. Thanks all!

Comment: No, that's not right. Only the single line must indeed be placed into the `ftdetect/go.vim` file. Something else is missing. Do you have both `:filetype on` and `:syntax on` in your `~/.vimrc`?!

Comment: Huh, I'll revisit, but syntax highlighting only worked when I copied ~/.vim/syntax/go.vim to ~/.vim/ftdetect/go.vim and appended 'au BufRead,BufNewFile *.go set filetype=go'. I do not have a ~/.vimrc file. It looks like it would make things convenient, as the above answer suggests but do you know what negative effects having redundant code in ~/.vim/ftdetect/go.vim might cause and why, in the absence of ~/.vimrc configuration this seems to work?