# GoLang Highlighting in vim not working

Tags: vim, go

I've seen multiple places(including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579822/add-golang-syntax-highlighting-for-vim)) that to add syntax highlighting you have to add certain lines to the .vimrc:

```
"Stuff for GoLang"
filetype off
filetype plugin indent off
set runtimepath+=$GOROOT/misc/vim
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

That is what's currently in my .vimrc
Restarted vim, terminal, system, and still no highlighting. Any suggestions?

Okay guys, I go the answer:

`$GOROOT` needs to be defined or you can simply put the location of your go installation.

Comment: do you have GOROOT environment variable defined?
Try running "echo $GOROOT" in a shell.

Comment: Output nothing @kostya

Comment: But the `$GOROOT` is only for go installations not in `/usr/local` right? @kostya

Comment: if GOROOT is not defined then the following line from your .vimrc "set runtimepath+=$GOROOT/misc/vim" cannot find a directory with plugin.

Comment: Try to find where $GOROOT/misc/vim is installed on your PC and if it is not there just download go sources and unpack it somewhere. Then modify the runtimepath line to point to the right location.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the corresponding runtime files are actually there.

1. `$GOROOT` must be defined; check with `:echo $GOROOT`
2. There must a *syntax plugin* (`syntax/go.vim`) below `$GOROOT/misc/vim`. Check with `:echo filereadable($GOROOT . '/misc/vim/syntax/go.vim')`.
3. After opening a Go file, you can check again via `:scriptnames` and `:syntax list`.