# how to turn syntax on in vim for golang for both root user and normal user mode?

Tags: vim, go

I modified ~/.vimrc and added the following line:

```
syntax on
```

to turn syntax on. The syntax is highlighted for python, java, but for golang it doesn't highlight at all.

I would like to do the same when editing vim files, logged in as root too. 
I tried to modify vimrc as root but none of the modes work with syntax.

Comment: Is it a difference in PATH? (and why would you ever need to edit Go code as root?)

Comment: I think it is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579822/add-golang-syntax-highlighting-for-vim

Comment: It seems like you need to install a go language support plugin. To configure this for root, simply add this to the root user's config file (it's probably in `/root/.vimrc`, unless if your root user has a different home directory).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add GoLang syntax highlighting for VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579822/add-golang-syntax-highlighting-for-vim)